# How to read BSQ file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read a .bsq file in R using the following command:

**read.ENVI("filename.bsq", ".hdr", sep = "")**

I get the following error:

*Error in read.ENVI("filename.bsq",  : unused argument (sep = "")*

And even if I remove the "sep" condition, I again get an error.

Can anyone help ?
Thanks

Comment: The [R-documentation](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/caTools/html/ENVI.html) for `read.ENVI` suggests `read.ENVI(filename, headerfile=paste(filename, ".hdr", sep=""))`. Maybe you should try it this way.

Comment: I tried this as well. The error is: Could not open input header file